# Why do we need to add a URL via netsh when listening to "http://*:8080" using HttpListener, but not when creating an HTTP server in Asp.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Recently I am writing an HTTP server using `HttpListener` and met a problem.

I want my program listen to all IP address on port 8080. However I have to either run the program as administrator or add url `http://*:8080` using `netsh`, otherwise it will throw an exception.

As far as I know, the built-in server like `IIS` or `HttpSys` from Asp.NET core can do the similar thing by just listening to IP address `0.0.0.0` without any administrator privileges or netsh thing.

How can they do this?

Edit:
I start an `HttpListener` like below:

```cs
var _listener = new HttpListener();
_listener.Prefixes.Add($"http://*:8080/");
_listener.Start(); // <-- Thrown exception "Access Denied" here
```

Comment: 1. please paste the relative code? 2. tried bigger ports such as 18080? because some smaller ports may need administrator privileges.

Comment: IIS needs admin privileges to setup, and parts of it run as Local System

Comment: The built in server for .net core is Kestrel.  Also please post a fully reproducible example otherwise there is no way for us to know exactly what the problem is

Comment: @LeiYang I add an example.

Comment: please try port in range `1025-65535`

Comment: @LeiYang no, it doesn't work.

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro does Kestrel needs admin privilege to listen to calls from any IP address?

Comment: have you tried a non-privileged port like a high number 61500 or something like that?

Comment: Tried but no luck

Comment: How you build this web application? Directly running inside a main console or else?

Comment: @BrandoZhang I run it under debug mode